# Android - VideoView inside Recyclerview match parent width and keep aspect ratio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-videoview

This is the part of the layout:

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/commentMediaContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/commentMediaLoading"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/commentMediaVideo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this inside `RecyclerView`:

```
        holder.commentMediaVideo.setVideoPath(fileUrl)
        holder.commentMediaVideo.setOnPreparedListener { mp ->
            mp.start()
            mp.isLooping = true

            holder.commentMediaVideo.requestLayout()
            holder.commentMediaContainer.requestLayout()
        }
```

The video matches the parent but the height isn't correct.

How can I make VideoView show the video with correct Aspect Ratio?

When I try `wrap_content` instead of `0dp` on `commentMediaVideo` then the video doesn't show at all!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a custom `VideoView` with overridden `onMeasure()` method as follows
And use `MyVideoView` in layout

```
class MyVideoView : VideoView {
    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context) 
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) 
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyleAttr
    )

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    constructor(
        context: Context?,
        attrs: AttributeSet?,
        defStyleAttr: Int,
        defStyleRes: Int
    ) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
    

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        setMeasuredDimension(
            getDefaultSize(suggestedMinimumWidth, widthMeasureSpec),
            getDefaultSize(suggestedMinimumHeight, heightMeasureSpec)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, after adding this class I only need to use <de.bla.pagagename.classes.MyVideoView instead of <VideoView inside the layout and nothing in the Kotlin code? If so it changes nothing